# Find and replace line matching a pattern in eclipse

Tags: regex, eclipse, findandmodify

What is the regex pattern to find and replace a line in eclipse ?

I am using this pattern `\S*\text\S*` and it replaces only the word but not the whole line matching the pattern

Comment: Use `.*text.*`....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following regexp:

```
^.*text.*$
```